# Jquery get input field value after click search

Tags: jquery

I want get the value from my input and insert in my span, so if the user search for mama and click search I should get what the user typed , in the case mama.

http://jsfiddle.net/4a9b7ovw/2/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#textinput").keyup(function() {
    alert(this.value);
    $('#result').show(this.value);
  });
  
  $("button").bind("click", function() {
    $(this).prop("#result");
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<input id="textinput" size="45" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="search" class="form-control input-md">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>

<div>
  You are search for: <span id="result"> </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.text()` and not `.show()`

result : `$('#result').text(this.value);`

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#textinput").keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
    {
      $("button").trigger("click")
    }
    //alert(this.value);
    //$('#result').text(this.value);
  });
  
  $("button").bind("click", function() {
    $('#result').html($("#textinput").val())
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<input id="textinput" size="45" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="search" class="form-control input-md">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>

<div>
  You are search for: <span id="result"> </span>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, how can make the (enter) in the keyboard by valid so I can click in the button search and (enter) in my keyboard.

Comment: @Raduken Try now, i've added the code so enter key will trigger the button

Answer (score 1):

Use `$("#result").html($("#textinput").val());`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#textinput").keyup(function() {
    $('#result').show(this.value);
  });

  $("button").bind("click", function() {
    $("#result").html($("#textinput").val());
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#textinput").on("keyup",function(e) {
    if(e.which != 13)
    $('#result').html("")
  });
  
  $("#textinput").on("keypress",function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13)
     $('#someButton').trigger("click")

  });
  
  $("button").bind("click", function() {
    $('#result').html($("#textinput").val())
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<input id="textinput" size="45" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="search" class="form-control input-md">

<button type="button" id="someButton" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>

<div>
  You are search for: <span id="result"> </span>
</div>
```

per your question in your comment see update

Comment: thank you, how can make the (enter) in the keyboard by valid so I can click in the button search and (enter) in my keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
 $("#result").text($("#textinput").val());
```

Answer (score 1):

change below line :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#textinput").keyup(function() {
    alert(this.value);
    **$('#result').text(this.value);**
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("button").bind("click", function() {
    $('#result').html($("#textinput").val());
});
```